# Throttling Ajax Requests on.('changeColor')/mousemove Event for Bootstrap Color Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7khb5L2m/

As you can see, everytime you choose or scroll through the colors, dozens if not hundreds of AJAX requests are performed.

```
$(function() {
    $('#cp7').colorpicker({
        customClass: 'colorpicker-2x',
        container: true,
        inline: true,
        sliders: {
            saturation: {
                maxLeft: 155,
                maxTop: 60
            },
            hue: {
                maxTop: 60
            },
            alpha: {
                maxTop: 60
            }
        }
    }).on('changeColor', function(e) {
        $('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = e.color.toString(
            'rgba');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: {'color':e.color.toString('rgba')},
            url: 'sessionbg.php'
        });
    });
});
```

I won't include it as it's not particularly relevant, but `sessionbg.php` just currently takes the color picked, and put's it into the users PHP `$_SESSION` variable.

I've tried adding a timeout so that one request is only conducted every 3 seconds (assuming after the user has picked a color and that color remains the same for 3 seconds)

https://jsfiddle.net/w2x0ugrs/

But this actually seems to make it worse in a way, and consistently throws ajax requests even when the user is not messing with the colorpicker and doesn't seem to have a delay when using the colorpicker!

Looking to integrate this to my live server soon, but really worried about crashing the server with so many AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `jQuery` you could use this [jQuery throttle / debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) plugin. The `$.debounce` function of this plugin makes it possible to prevent a function from being called over and over again without an interval between it.

I've implemented the plugin in the example below. `$.debounce` has two parameters. The `interval` is a number that indicates the time between calls that have to occur before the second parameter `callback` is being called.

Play with the `interval` argument to get the perfect setting.

```
$(function() {

    function postColor(color) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: {'color': color.toString('rgba')},
            url: 'sessionbg.php'
        });
    }

    var debouncedPostColor = $.debounce(250, postColor);

    $('#cp7').colorpicker({
        customClass: 'colorpicker-2x',
        container: true,
        inline: true,
        sliders: {
            saturation: {
                maxLeft: 155,
                maxTop: 60
            },
            hue: {
                maxTop: 60
            },
            alpha: {
                maxTop: 60
            }
        }
    }).on('changeColor', function(e) {
        $('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = e.color.toString('rgba');
        debouncedPostColor(e.color);
    });
});
```

You could also try `$.throttle` which will call the `callback` every `N` seconds the `callback` is being called.

Comment: That works quite good, thanks.  Note your `}));` has to be second from bottom rather than first at the end to work-- only downside is that this also delays the `$('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = e.color.toString(
            'rgba');` so the background color change is not fluid.  Is there anyway to use `$.debounce` for just the ajax requests and not the entire `.on('changeColor')` event?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've modified the example by placing the `$.ajax` call in a seperate function and create a debounced version of it so only the AJAX request will wait.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you again, works exactly as intended.